# AzureAD B2C - AddMicrosoftIdentityUserAuthenticationHandler does not work as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web

I am using AzureB2C with a number of dotnet6.0 WebApps and WebAPI applications. One of my WebApps calls two different WebAPIs, both of which are registered, along with their scopes, in AzureB2C. Typically, in my controller code, I inject the ITokenAcquisition component and call GetAccessTokenForUserAsync("[scopes]") to get an access token which I can then add to the HttpClient. This all works fine, but I would like to be a bit smarter and define the token acquisition in my Startup class as follows.

[image]

You can see that I want to define my HttpClient to use the extension method "AddMicrosoftIdentityUserAuthenticationHandler". There is very little documentation on this but there is [a sample on GitHub here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/3-WebApp-multi-APIs).

I would expect to inject my HttpFactory class into the Controller and create a client of type "auth_client". Microsoft Identity should then deal with acquiring the access token. I simply cannot get this to work.

Does anyone know if this works with Azure AD B2C or is it only designed to work against Azure AD?

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more details about _"I simply cannot get this to work."_ ? Do you  get some exceptions, errors, timeouts or similar?

Comment: @Trinimon I would expect MicrosoftIdentity to acquire an access token and inject this into the header for the HttpClient which gets injected into the  Controller. However, it does nothing. When inspecting the HttpClient instance which gets injected, there is no Authentication header. I don't know how else I can find out what is going on. Thanks for any pointers.